# POST-ответ от сервера

Tags: php, http

Имеется пхп-скрипт, который принимает пост-дату. Я проверяю эту дату и мне нужно отправить "true" или "false". Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
if ($allRight) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
};
```

Или так:

```
return ($allRight) ? true : false;
```

Comment: @kirill не вижу смысла писать тернарный оператор там, где не знают базис языка. Тогда уж еще каст надо привести как пример, чтобы запутать окончательно :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$allRight = 'text';
//$allRight = true;
//$allRight = false;

var_dump(var_export($allRight == true, true));
```

Comment: Специально для неучей-минусующих обновил пост.